# Como fazer meu servidor feito em python funcionar em rede externa usando o ngrok?

Tags: python, servidor, socket

Eu criei um server em python que roda na porta 50000... Logo após disso criei meu cliente. Se os dois estiverem na mesma rede ambos se conectam e da tudo certo! Porém em rede externa não consigo fazer a conexão com os dois.
Então descobri uma ferramenta chamada ngrok, fiz download dela e comecei a usar. Eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma:
Executo meu servidor na porta 50000 a após isso executo o seguinte comando:
`ngrok.exe http 50000`
O ngrok funciona, abre o link e beleza, mas quando eu entro no link gerado o meu servidor feito em python se conecta com o que eu acho ser o ngrok, pois ele me retorna isso:

```
Host: 66907fd55f8a.ngrok.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Forwarded-For: Meu ip
X-Forwarded-Proto: https


Digite o comando:
```

Mas eu quero que o meu cliente se conecte ao servidor para eu mandar comandos para ele.

O código resumido do servidor e do cliente, ele está resumido pois está bem longo, pois em ambos os códigos eu adicionei varias funções:
servidor.py:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

def abrir_servidor():
    bind_ip = ''  # local onde o servidor roda
    # bind_ip = ''
    bind_port = 50000  # porta onde roda o servidor

    print('Iniciando servidor: ')
    sleep(0.5)

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
    server.listen(1)

    print('Servidor iniciado!')

    print('Aguardando cliente...')
    global conexao
    global endereco
    conexao, endereco = server.accept()
    print(f'Conectado em: {endereco}')
def main():
    abrir_servidor()
    while True:
        global comandos
        comandos = input('Digite o comando: ')
        


while True:
    main()
```

cliente.py:

```
import socket
import os

def conectar():
    #conectando no servidor:
    target_host = 'localhost'
    target_port = 50000
    global cliente
    cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    cliente.connect((target_host, target_port))
    # localizar script:
    for a in range(1):
        cliente.send(os.getcwd().encode())
        
def main():
    conectar()
    while True:
        global comandos
        comandos = cliente.recv(4000).decode()
        
while True:
    main()
```

Como eu faço isso? Já estou ficando sem ideias. Será que existe outro jeito de fazer meu servidor rodar em rede externa?

Comment: Consegue editar a pergunta e colocar o código do servidor ou, caso ele seja muito grande, 
um [mcve]? Fica mais simples para tentar responder, caso seja um problema no código e não na infraestrutura 
(rede, firewall, etc).

Comment: Eu acabei de editar a pergunta, colocando o código do cliente e do servidor. Obrigado pela dica de adiciona-los, tinha até me esquecido

Comment: Quando você diz "na mesma rede", quer dizer no mesmo computador? Ou em computadores 
diferentes conectados por uma rede? A conexão do cliente está apontando para
'localhost', o que sugere que os dois programas estão rodando na mesma máquina. O código inicial do servidor está correto, falta apenas o recebimento da primeira mensagem (os.getcwd) e
o envio (para o cliente) dos comandos digitados.

Comment: Mesma rede eu digo tanto na mesma maquina quanto em computadores diferentes conectados na mesma rede wifi. No código esta localhost pois eu estava testando no meu pc. Sobre o recebimento da mensagem (os.getcwd) já arrumei. Mas ainda não sei como deixar meu servidor pronto para receber clientes em rede externa.

Answer (score 1):

No contexto de servidores, o endereço `0.0.0.0` significa *todos os endereços IPv4 na máquina local*. Se um *host* tiver dois endereços IPs, por exemplo: `192.168.1.1` e `10.1.2.1`, e um servidor em execução estiver escutando no endereço `0.0.0.0`, ele estará acessível para ambos os IPs.

Portanto, use o endereço `0.0.0.0` para fazer o `bind` da porta na qual o seu servidor vai escutar, por exemplo:

```
bind_ip = '0.0.0.0'  # local onde o servidor roda
bind_port = 50000    # porta onde roda o servidor
```

Isso vai fazer com que seu servidor aceite conexões independente da origem.

Referência: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0